# Class with no destructor returns copy of object but when I add a destructor it returns the same object

Tags: c++, c++11, destructor, copy-constructor

I was playing around with classes in C++, specifically implementing a private constructor with a static "create" function that returns the object.

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    static Foo create_foo() {    
        Foo foo{};
        std::cout << "Foo::create_foo():: Address of foo: " << &foo << std::endl;

        return foo;
    }
private:
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::Foo():: Constructor" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    auto foo = Foo::create_foo();
    std::cout << "main():: Address of foo: " << &foo << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Running the code above creates two different `Foo` objects: one in `Foo::create_foo()` and one in `main()` as seen from the output:

```sh
Foo::Foo():: Constructor
Foo::create_foo():: Address of foo: 0x7ffe5d5e60bf
main():: Address of foo: 0x7ffe5d5e60ef
```

My first inclination was "okay, it's calling the copy constructor." So I added the following *public* copy constructor:

```cpp
Foo(Foo const&) { std::cout << "Foo::Foo(Foo const&):: Copy constructor" << std::endl; }
```

This is where my confusion lies, by simply adding a copy constructor, `Foo::create_foo()` and `main()` now contain the same object:

```sh
Foo::Foo():: Constructor
Foo::create_foo():: Address of foo: 0x7ffe53c9d63f
main():: Address of foo: 0x7ffe53c9d63f
```

This same behavior happens as well if I add a *public* destructor:

```cpp
~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo():: Destructor" << std::endl; }
```

Output:

```sh
Foo::Foo():: Constructor
Foo::create_foo():: Address of foo: 0x7ffed84a400f
main():: Address of foo: 0x7ffed84a400f
Foo::~Foo():: Destructor
```

I am just curious as to why adding an additional (copy) constructor or destructor changes the behavior of my static function. Could it be some compiler optimization? I am using `gcc version 10.2.1 20201125 (Red Hat 10.2.1-9) (GCC)` and compiling without any flags (`g++ -o main main.cpp`).

Comment: [NRVO](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) might apply.

Comment: Since the class has no member variables, it may have an unusual optimization pattern.  Add in a `int data[50];` and see if that changes the behavior.  And try with and without optimizations enabled.

Comment: Note that there is also "copy assignment", not only copy construction. I think "copy assignment" is what you have on your first line in main. Or even move assignment.

Comment: Also note that when you implement the copy constructor or a destructor, the compiler will not create default move constructor/assignment operations for you anymore.

Comment: @P.Saladin: `auto foo = Foo::create_foo();` doesn't use assignment, but copy/move constructor (unless elided of course (which is mandatory since C++17))

Answer (score 1):

All the potential copies/moves of `Foo` in the code are allowed to be elided by the compiler. Since C++17 this is even mandatory for all but the move construction of the return value of `create_foo` from `foo`.

This latter case is called *named return value optimization* and is still an optional optimization that the compiler may choose to apply and elide the constructor call.

You are not compiling with optimizations enabled. Add the `-O2` flag and the NRVO is applied in all cases you describe.

I don't know why GCC does apply NRVO even without optimization flags only if you add the special member functions, but it may be equally surprising that it applies the NRVO at all without optimization flags.

With NRVO applied (and all other elisions also applied, whether mandatory or not), there will be only a single `Foo` object, directly constructed by `create_foo` into `foo` in `main`.